# Does the HTML5 Canvas have a "pen down" method?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

The Python module Turtle has a method called `pendown()`. When called, it causes a line to be drawn wherever the turtle moves. (The Python docs use the definition "Pull the pen down – drawing when moving.")

However, the HTML5 `<canvas>` element does not seem to have implemented a method similar to this; could I have missed something in my research?

Comment: Canvas paths are acceptable in the use case I have in mind.

Comment: Short answer. No. You have to make your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there isn't something like the good old Turtle baked into JavaScript already, you can kind of do the same thing.

With canvas you can move your 'pen' using the `CanvasRenderingContext.moveTo(x,y)` function. If this command is followed by a call `to lineTo(x,y)` and subsequently by `stroke()`, it would draw a straight line in-between the two points. As you might guess, if you do not call stroke(), there will be no line! So if you write two helper functions `penDown()` `penUp()` you can toggle between moveTo/lineTo and ultimately replicate the behaviour of the turtle.

Here's an example (just click on 'Run code snippet'):

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
let penState = "up";
let prevPosition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

context.lineWidth = 1;

function go(x, y) {
  if (penState == "up") {
    context.moveTo(x, y);
  } else {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(prevPosition.x, prevPosition.y);
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
  }
  prevPosition.x = x;
  prevPosition.y = y;
}

function penDown() {
  penState = "down";
}

function penUp() {
  penState = "up";
}

go(50, 50);
penDown();
go(100, 50);
penUp();
go(75, 25);
penDown();
go(50, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background-color: lightgrey;"></canvas>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3oszyj15/ This draws several times on the previous lines, resulting in darker lines.

Comment: Good catch @Kaiido - thanks! I've corrected the code!

Comment: closePath is useless though, it's just a lineTo, it doesn't tell the path is ended, but enclosed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a js object called turtle with a boolean penDown property and use that to draw on the canvas.

Source for this answer(includes code example):
https://cnx.org/contents/hTEMulu8@2/Turtle-graphics-with-the-HTML5-canvas

Answer (score 0):

Though there isn't something like the turtle library in Javascript, there is an easy way to replicate the `pendown()` effect

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas") // Gets Element Using CSS Syntax
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // Gets Context from Canvas

ctx.moveTo(0, 0) // Use ctx.moveTo(x, y) when wanting to move while Pen Up
ctx.lineTo(50, 50) // Use ctx.lineTo(x, y) when wanting to move while Pen Down
```

Comment: I did actually know of `.lineTo()` (simply retrieve the next coordinate pairs from my array of Voronoi cells), but I thought it a bit inelegant. Unfortunately, it appears that there is built-in way to replicate the `.penDown` functionality.